# Create Bar Chart With Relative Frequency / From Table Object in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, percentage

I have a dataset about accidents in the UK. Among other variables it contains the month of the accident and the severity (ranging from 1 to 3). Thus, you can imagine the dataset like this:

| ID | Month | Accident_Severity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 3 |
| 2 | 01 | 2 |
| 3 | 04 | 1 |
| 4 | 07 | 2 |

I would like to produce a bar chart with the months on the x-axis and the relative share of accidents out of the given severity class that happend in this month on the y-axis. This means each month should have three bars, let's say red, blue and green. Summing the relative share indicated by all bars of one color should equal to 100% for each color. I.e. if blue means Accident_Severity = 2 and the blue bar indicates 10% for January, this would mean 10% of all accidents with severity of 2 happend in january.

I managed to get these numbers as a table doing the following:

```
pivot_rel <- df %>%
  select(month, Accident_Severity) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  table()

for (i in c(1,2,3)) {
  for (j in seq(1,12)) {
    pivot_rel[j,i] <- round(pivot_rel[j,i]/sum_severity[i],3)
  }
}

pivot_rel
```

[pivot_rel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrXWP.png)

However, i cannot use the object with ggplot. When trying I receive the error: "Fehler: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class table"

How do I visualize this table or is there an easier way to do what I try to achieve? Many Thanks!

Comment: Could you please paste a chunk of representative data into the question using `dput(df)` to make the question reproducible. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xtabs` to table the data and `colSums` to get the proportions. Then, with packages `ggplot2` and `scales`, plot the graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

tbl <- xtabs( ~ Month + Accident_Severity, df1)
t(tbl)/colSums(tbl)
#                 Month
#Accident_Severity   1   4   7
#                1 0.0 1.0 0.0
#                2 0.5 0.0 0.5
#                3 1.0 0.0 0.0

as.data.frame(t(tbl)/colSums(tbl)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(factor(Month), Freq, fill = factor(Accident_Severity))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  xlab("Month") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Accident Severity"))
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID  Month   Accident_Severity
1   01  3
2   01  2
3   04  1
4   07  2
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to change table to dataframe which can be used with `ggplot`.

```
pivot_rel <- as.data.frame.matrix(pivot_rel)
```

---

However, you might also go a step back and use `count` instead of `table` to generate the frequency counts of `month` and  `Accident_Severity`.

```
library(dplyr)

pivot_rel <- df %>% count(month, Accident_Severity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using  `proportions` on `xtabs` and base `barplot`.

```
proportions(xtabs( ~ Month + Accident_Severity, d), margin=2) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  with(barplot(Freq ~ Accident_Severity + Month, beside=T, col=2:4,
               main='Relative Frequencies', 
               legend.text=sort(unique(d$Accident_Severity)),
               args.legend=list(title='Accident_Severity')))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
  d <- read.table(header=T, text='
                ID  Month   Accident_Severity
1   01  3
2   01  2
3   04  1
4   07  2')
```